# Rider EAP wwwroot hidden

Tags: .net-core, macos-sierra, rider

I'm working with the February 2017 Rider EAP build on macOS Sierra. I added a `wwwroot` folder to my project and when I installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` assembly. The folder disappeared from the Project View. It's definitely there, and when running the web app it correctly serves content from this directory, but it's not visible in Rider, and I get warnings about my static resources not being available. Is this a known issue or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

we're working on support .net core right now. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-3777